# Change color of selected and make rounded corners for each cell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Whenever I select a cell in a table view the cell background quickly changes to the color blue. Is there a way to change it to any other color and make rounded corners for each cell ?

Comment: y cant u create a cell like that

Answer (score 0):

you can use UItableViewCell property

```
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
```

but u just have two choices only ..either blue or gray

Answer (score 0):

Use `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;` or `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue`. And for the rounded corners case use

```
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

hi try this may this help you...

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray; // this line for selection style
```

here 3 types of selection style are

1.UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue

2.UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray

3.UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone

```
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8; /// this line for round corner
```

hope this help you...

:)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `cell.selectionStyle` then you can use only three colors.

If you want to use more colors then use something like the code below:

```
UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
myBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:0.75 alpha:1];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;
[myBackView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can setYour view to your cell when selectRow.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = YourView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new view and assign it to `selectedBackgroundView` property of the cell.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell
    let backgroundView = UIView()
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
    backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    cell!.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView
    return cell!
}
```